# Linux watch command: "--differences" not working

Tags: mysql, linux, watch

I would like to use the linux `watch` command and have seen that there may be a "culmulative" (`--differences=`) parameter but this doesnt appear to be working.

Basically I would like to do the following and not have watch refresh the screen as i need to keep track of whats happening:

```
watch  mysqladmin -uroot -pxxx processlist
```

If watch wont work here is there an alternative?

Comment: I found an `--differences` switch which means "cumulative". Edited post. And maybe I'm wrong, but shouldn't you add `--differences` in your command if you want to use it? I refer to procps 3.2.8 (Debian Squeeze).

Answer (score 1):

Why not redirect output to a file using

```
>>
```

And then do `tailf` on that file ?

Answer (score 1):

```
watch  mysqladmin -uroot -pxxx processlist
```

Works for me. Keep in mind that "-p" is a command line option for "watch". Try:

```
watch -n 1 mysqladmin --user=<user> --password=<password> processlist
```

Or simply use http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/ ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
while true; do mysqladmin -uroot -pxxx processlist; sleep 1; done
```

maybe?